# How to get same URL parameter in two function?

Tags: php

How to get same URL parameter in two functions using PHP?
If I do it like this, is it right or wrong? I want to get the value of the URL in both functions

```
public function getcountylocateAction(){`$_GET('link');`}
public function countrylocatorAction(){`$_GET('link');`}
```

Comment: I  don't know where is the problem?

 getcountylocateAction($link=$_GET['link']){echo $link;} 
 countrylocatorAction($link=$_GET['link']){echo $link;}

Comment: it doesnt work bro

Comment: The `GET` only contains `GET` parameters if you want the URL look at `$_SERVER` values. It also is unclear of how it fails to work for your. The provided code would do nothing.

Comment: The [backtick operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php) is used to run shell commands. It doesn't make sense to use it to run PHP code—you're already inside PHP!

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is global array variable

it should be $_GET['link']

for more information look on documentation
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0):

$_GET is not a function so i am hoping you are getting some errors while doing so.
You can either assign this parameter to a variable and use that variable in both functions or you can use the $_GET["link"].

```
$link = $_GET["link"];
public function getcountylocateAction(){$_GET["link"];}
public function countrylocatorAction(){$_GET["link"];}
```